# How to detect if a clicked div is above or below a specific div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html structure like this:

```
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="exit-row"><div class="exit-title">Exit</div></div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="exit-row"><div class="exit-title">Exit</div></div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div><div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to detect if the div I clicked '.seat-row' is 'above', 'below' or 'between' the '.exit-row'.

I must do it with javascript, not jquery or other libraries

i try to add class each 'seat-row' number, after '.exit-row' parent '.seat-row' add class 'exit-door' and split the class

Comment: I edited your question, but I couldn't understand the last sentence. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: What do you mean by "'between' the '.exit-row'"? How can something be between 1 element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on the objective here but I am focusing on answering "*I want to detect if the div I clicked '.seat-row' is 'above', 'below' or 'between' the '.exit-row'*".

You can loop through all of your `.seat-row` elements and attach an event listener that gets the current element's index as well as the indexes of the exits. From there you are just comparing the current index to those exit indexes to see if you are above, below, or between the exits.

This code is assuming everything is exactly like your provided HTML and so the only thing to work with are the classes (no `id` attributes for identification).

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".seat-row").forEach(el => {
  if(!el.querySelector(".exit-row")) el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let saveIndex,
        exitIndexes = []
    document.querySelectorAll(".seat-row").forEach((list, index) => {
      if(list.querySelector(".exit-row")) exitIndexes = [...exitIndexes, index]
      if(list == e.target.closest(".seat-row")) saveIndex = index
    })
    
    console.log(`above: ${(exitIndexes.filter(i => i < saveIndex).length <= 0) ? "Yes" : "No"} | below: ${(exitIndexes.filter(i => i > saveIndex).length <= 0) ? "Yes" : "No"} | between: ${(exitIndexes.filter(i => i < saveIndex).length > 0 && exitIndexes.filter(i => i > saveIndex).length > 0) ? "Yes" : "No"}`)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="exit-row"><div class="exit-title">Exit</div></div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="exit-row"><div class="exit-title">Exit</div></div>
</div>
<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div><div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="seat-row">
    <div class="seat-row-inner">
        <div class="seat-group">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, alias, aliquid, asperiores atque autem
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```